# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is present on the requested resource" error for css file

Tags: javascript, css, sdk, access-control, response-headers

I created an sdk. When the css file is to be loaded, it gives this error.

The css file includes a .woff2 url for the font.

Even after removing that part of the code, the error persists.

I don't know how to handle this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding:

```
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
```

in the nginx config file in the respective location block solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a .htaccess header. Red more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

You have to remove this header in order to access this file.

Or set it to:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: Where shall I add the header?

Comment: inside the .htacces `<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>`

Comment: Hi @Winter if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Should I create an .htaccess file and add the header setting in that?

Comment: @Winter if you use apache as your webserver just add it inside the root httpdocs folder.

Comment: But I'm not using apache. I'm using nginx server.

Comment: Added the header to nginx settings. It's working. Thanks.